# How to continue training with checkpoints using object_detector.EfficientDetLite4Spec tensorflow lite

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow-lite

Preciously I have set my EfficientDetLite4 model *"grad_checkpoint=true"* in config.yaml. And it had successfully generated some checkpoints. However, I can't figure out how to use these checkpoints when I want to continue training based on them.

**Every time I train the model it just start from the beginning, not from my checkpoints.**

The following picture shows my colab file system structure:

[image: my colab file system structure]

The following picture shows where my checkpoints store:

[image: model file system here]

The following code shows how I configure the model and how I train with the model.

```
import numpy as np
import os

from tflite_model_maker.config import ExportFormat
from tflite_model_maker import model_spec
from tflite_model_maker import object_detector

import tensorflow as tf
assert tf.__version__.startswith('2')

tf.get_logger().setLevel('ERROR')
from absl import logging
logging.set_verbosity(logging.ERROR)

train_data, validation_data, test_data = 
    object_detector.DataLoader.from_csv('csv_path')

spec = object_detector.EfficientDetLite4Spec(
    uri='/content/model',
    model_dir='/content/drive/MyDrive/MathSymbolRecognition/CheckPoints/',
    hparams='grad_checkpoint=true,strategy=gpus',
    epochs=50, batch_size=3,
    steps_per_execution=1, moving_average_decay=0,
    var_freeze_expr='(efficientnet|fpn_cells|resample_p6)',
    tflite_max_detections=25, strategy=spec_strategy
)

model = object_detector.create(train_data, model_spec=spec, batch_size=3, 
    train_whole_model=True, validation_data=validation_data)
```

Comment: Did you find the answer ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### The source code is the answer !

I ran into the same problem and found out that the `model_dir` we pass to the TFLite model Maker's object detector API is ***only used for saving*** the model's weights: that's why the API never restores from checkpoints.

Having a look at the source code of this API, I noticed it internally uses the standard `model.compile` and `model.fit` functions and it saves the model's weights through the `callbacks` parameter of `model.fit`. 
This means that, provided that we can get the interal keras model, we can just restore our checkpoints by using `model.load_weights` !

These are the links to the source code if you want to know more about what some of the functions I use below do:

- [Object Detector Documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/api_docs/python/tflite_model_maker/object_detector/ObjectDetector)
- [Object Detector Source Code](https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/blob/189c662d500c20b9f9e93fef0af97d5311e64377/tensorflow_examples/lite/model_maker/core/task/object_detector.py#L92)
- [EfficientDetSpec Source Code](https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/blob/189c662d500c20b9f9e93fef0af97d5311e64377/tensorflow_examples/lite/model_maker/core/task/model_spec/object_detector_spec.py#L241)
- [How the TFLite Model Maker API Compiles your Model](https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/blob/189c662d500c20b9f9e93fef0af97d5311e64377/tensorflow_examples/lite/model_maker/third_party/efficientdet/keras/train.py#L111)

This is the code:

```py
#Useful imports
import tensorflow as tf
from tflite_model_maker.config import QuantizationConfig
from tflite_model_maker.config import ExportFormat
from tflite_model_maker import model_spec
from tflite_model_maker import object_detector
from tflite_model_maker.object_detector import DataLoader

#Import the same libs that TFLiteModelMaker interally uses
from tensorflow_examples.lite.model_maker.third_party.efficientdet.keras import train
from tensorflow_examples.lite.model_maker.third_party.efficientdet.keras import train_lib



#Setup variables
batch_size = 6 #or whatever batch size you want
epochs = 50
checkpoint_dir = "/content/..." #whatever your checkpoint directory is



#Create whichever object detector's spec you want
spec = object_detector.EfficientDetLite4Spec(
    model_name='efficientdet-lite4',
    uri='https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/efficientdet/lite4/feature-vector/2', 
    hparams='', #enable grad_checkpoint=True if you want
    model_dir=checkpoint_dir, 
    epochs=epochs, 
    batch_size=batch_size,
    steps_per_execution=1, 
    moving_average_decay=0,
    var_freeze_expr='(efficientnet|fpn_cells|resample_p6)',
    tflite_max_detections=25, 
    strategy=None, 
    tpu=None, 
    gcp_project=None,
    tpu_zone=None, 
    use_xla=False, 
    profile=False, 
    debug=False, 
    tf_random_seed=111111,
    verbose=1
)



#Load you datasets
train_data, validation_data, test_data = object_detector.DataLoader.from_csv('/path/to/csv.csv')




#Create the object detector 
detector = object_detector.create(
    train_data, 
    model_spec=spec, 
    batch_size=batch_size, 
    train_whole_model=True, 
    validation_data=validation_data,
    epochs = epochs,
    do_train = False
)



"""
From here on we use internal/"private" functions of the API,
you can tell because the methods' names begin with an underscore
"""

#Convert the datasets for training
train_ds, steps_per_epoch, _ = detector._get_dataset_and_steps(train_data, batch_size, is_training = True)
validation_ds, validation_steps, val_json_file = detector._get_dataset_and_steps(validation_data, batch_size, is_training = False)




#Get the internal keras model    
model = detector.create_model()




#Copy what the API internally does as setup
config = spec.config
config.update(
    dict(
        steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch,
        eval_samples=batch_size * validation_steps,
        val_json_file=val_json_file,
        batch_size=batch_size
    )
)
train.setup_model(model, config) #This is the model.compile call basically
model.summary()




"""
Here we restore the weights
"""

#Load the weights from the latest checkpoint.
#In my case:
#checkpoint_dir = "/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/checkpoints_heavy/" 
#specific_checkpoint_dir = "/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/checkpoints_heavy/ckpt-35"
try:
    #Option A:
    #load the weights from the last successfully completed epoch
    latest = tf.train.latest_checkpoint(checkpoint_dir) 

    #Option B:
    #load the weights from a specific checkpoint.
    #Note that there's no ".index" at the end of specific_checkpoint_dir
    #latest = specific_checkpoint_dir

    completed_epochs = int(latest.split("/")[-1].split("-")[1]) #the epoch the training was at when the training was last interrupted
    model.load_weights(latest)

    print("Checkpoint found {}".format(latest))
except Exception as e:
    print("Checkpoint not found: ", e)



#Retrieve the needed default callbacks
all_callbacks = train_lib.get_callbacks(config.as_dict(), validation_ds)



"""
Optional step.
Add callbacks that get executed at the end of every N 
epochs: in this case I want to log the training results to tensorboard.
"""
#tensorboard_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir=tensorboard_dir, histogram_freq=1)
#all_callbacks.append(tensorboard_callback)




"""
Train the model 
"""
model.fit(
    train_ds,
    epochs=epochs,
    initial_epoch=completed_epochs, 
    steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch,
    validation_data=validation_ds,
    validation_steps=validation_steps,
    callbacks=all_callbacks #This is for saving checkpoints at the end of every epoch + running the above added callbacks
)




"""
Save/export the trained model
Tip: for integer quantization you simply have to NOT SPECIFY 
the quantization_config parameter of the detector.export method.
In this case it would be: 
detector.export(export_dir = export_dir, tflite_filename='model.tflite')
"""
export_dir = "/content/..." #save the tflite wherever you want
quant_config = QuantizationConfig.for_float16() #or whatever quantization you want
detector.model = model #inject our trained model into the object detector
detector.export(export_dir = export_dir, tflite_filename='model.tflite', quantization_config = quant_config)
```

Comment: Has there been any official releases yet to restore checkpoint wise training ?

Comment: No update/news in that direction unfortunately. The workaround I've proposed still work but as you can see from google's own documentation (https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/api_docs/python/tflite_model_maker/object_detector/ObjectDetector) this API is still pretty much the same as it was at the time of the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much . Your contribution is valuable, I will try your script.

Comment: Am I right in assuming this only allows us to save a training session that is interrupted and export from the last successfully completed epoch?

This doesn't allow us to restart the training session from the checkpoint?

(Thankyou for the code, its great, just trying to wrap my head around it, and ultimately figure out a way to restart a training session from a last completed checkpoint)

Comment: Hi, to be clear this code doesn't do any saving operation, those are internally done by the TFLiteModelMaker API (it saves the weights of the model at the end of every successfully completed epoch inside the checkpoint_dir). Inside your checkpoint_dir you'll find the same files you would find if you called "tf.keras.model.save_weights" at the end of every epoch. I've updated the code so that it's now possible to choose which checkpoint your training should be resumed from ("OptionB" inside the try-catch block). Hope this helps you a bit!

Comment: Thank you so much! My classmates suggest me in the same way! As of the Chinese Nets I can't always log in to see your answer, sorry for that.

Comment: You're welcome! Don't worry about logging in, the important thing is that we've solved the issue :)

Comment: @CristianDavideConte out of interest can you access the metrics (loss, accuracy etc.) for the evaluate function using this same work around? referencing the internal/"private" functions of the api? any tips on how you would do this? This is a super interesting expansion upon the limited functionality of Model Maker

Comment: @Will If you mean the metrics that are updated during the training, you should be able to access them through a tensorboard callback/the optional part of my answer (just remember to set the callback parameter of model.fit to the callback variable created in that part). If you instead want to read the metrics of the detector.evaluate function, it return should them in a [str, float] dictionary (this is the source code of the "evaluate" function: https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/blob/master/tensorflow_examples/lite/model_maker/core/task/model_spec/object_detector_spec.py#L303-L346).

Comment: @CristianDavideConte First appreciate your efforts for digging out the source code. Here i am curious, is it possible/making sense to continue training with a different training dataset? (since the definition of epoch, is the complete pass of a fixed dataset, if let say at 30th epoch, I am adding a different dataset, is the training still improving gradually?

Comment: @CristianDavideConte To elaborate, let say i have a dataset A (100 images), take 1 hour to train (30 epochs). The evaluation metrics seem to hit plateau. Then i have a dataset B (100 images). Naively, I would add dataset A and B (200 images) and re-train.

So, my question is, is it possible to 'continue training' dataset B with the already-trained-dataset-A-model?

Comment: @zeroflaw yes, it is tecnically possible to use this method to continue the training in the situation you mentioned. You have to keep in mind that if you tell the model to train for 
 40 epochs totally and you've already trained for 30 of them, the learning rate won't be the same as it was at 0 epochs. This means that the second part of the training will be less effective (the model will learn less). To overcome this problem you have to add a callback that regulates the learning rate (this can be useful: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/callbacks/LearningRateScheduler).